How should I approch the bloc to bloc communication?
this is amongst one of my first questions here so I hope I can do a proper job asking it!
Situation:
I am using bloc(A) to retrieve some information from an API, this information is passed properly to the state that requires this data and then is presented to the user as desired.
class GetParticipantsBloc extends Bloc<GetParticipantsEvent, GetParticipantsState> {
  GetParticipantsBloc() : super(Loading()) {
    on<LoadParticipants>((event, emit) async {
      // Emit the loading state
      emit(Loading());

      //Inject the repository
      ExamRepository examRepository = getIt<ExamRepository>();

      // Simulate loading to see my loading functionality
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

      // Make the API call
      final dataState = await examRepository.getExamParticipants(event.exam);

      // If the API call was successful:
      if (dataState is DataSuccess){
        // Convert the raw data into a list of participants
        var j = jsonDecode(dataState.data);
        List<Participant> participants = List<Participant>.from(j.map((e) => Participant.fromJson(e)));

        // we set participants here in a static method so that I can have access the data in another bloc
        ParticipantsProvider.setParticipants(participants);

        // Emit the loaded state
        emit(ParticipantsLoaded(participants: participants));
      }

      // If the API call was unsuccessful:
      if (dataState is DataFailed){
        emit(LoadingFailed());
      }
    });
  }
}

Problem:
I now need to access the said data in bloc(B) that makes another call to the API to perform some action, but I don't know what is the proper way of doing it and I am looking for suggestions.
In short: How to make data from bloc(A) available to another bloc in the correct manner.
My solutions so far:
To create a static class () that I can store/fetch my data after bloc has successfully gotten it with the API call
class ParticipantsProvider{
  static List<Participant>? _participants;

  static void setParticipants(List<Participant> participants)
  {
    _participants = participants;
  }

  static List<Participant>? getParticipants()
  {
    return _participants;
  }
}


https://bloclibrary.dev/architecture/#bloc-to-bloc-communication

@pskink the document discusses a situation where a bloc need to respond to another bloc, I believe my situation is different as I am asking for the proper way of handling a data that my bloc is providing, and use that data in the constructor call of another bloc

how it is different? your situation is that bloc A emits some data and bloc B emits its data based on data received from bloc A, this is explained here: https://bloclibrary.dev/architecture/#connecting-blocs-through-domain

@pskink is right. Bloc to Bloc should be done via User Layer
